# Replace img src path but keep basename

Tags: python, string, replace

Working with a piece of software that randomly stores images on its filesystem, so I never know the path to the image or how many directories deep it is.

I want to replace this path, but keep the basename (basename is guaranteed to be last item in path).  Exactly like below.

**Input**

```
<img src="random/path/with/different/number/of/dirs/myImage.jpg"></img>
```

**Output**

```
<img src="http://somedomain.com/myImage.jpg"></img>
```

I don't think python's `string.replace()` is going to get me anywhere, but I am new to regex and don't really have a grasp on what I need to replace the path but keep the basename

Comment: use `bs4` to parse html to grab image src, use `os.path.basename(img_src)` to get basename and then `my_new_link = mydomain + basename`

Comment: @BijayRegmi I am limited to what's already installed on my machine and that excludes `beautifulsoup`, unfortunately.

Comment: How do you identify if you have right img then? Is there only one img tag in whole page? Do you have specific id or class attribute for the html tag? If you know your input is the right one, I think it is fairly straightforward, even with builtin libraries.

Comment: @BijayRegmi I'm replacing all images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small class to parse `<img>` tag using inbuilt `html.parser` class `HTMLParser`.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class MyImgParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.img_src = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'img':
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr[0] == 'src':
                    self.img_src = attr[1]

    def get_img_src(self):
        return self.img_src
```

Then I use this parser like:

```
myparser = MyImgParser()
myparser.feed('<img src="random/path/with/different/number/of/dirs/myImage.jpg"></img>')
img_src = myparser.get_img_src()
```

which gives `random/path/with/different/number/of/dirs/myImage.jpg`.

we can extract base name of file using `img_src = os.path.basename(img_src)` which gives us `myImage.jpg`. Now we can replace the link like:

```
my_new_img_link = "https://somedomain.com/" + img_src
```

Answer (score 1):

As i read from your answer on your question that you can't use external libraries, here is my solution:

```
test_str = '<img src="random/path/with/different/number/of/dirs/myImage.jpg"></img>'
 
start_str = 'src="'
end_str = '"'
 
# Getting the src string
index = test_str.index(start_str)
temp_str = test_str[index + len(start_str):]
index = temp_str.index(end_str)
temp_str = temp_str[0:index]

#Now remove basename from temp_str and replace the starting test_str with a custom url
index = temp_str.rfind('/')
temp_str = temp_str[:index]

end_str = test_str.replace(temp_str, "https://somedomain.com")

print(end_str)
```

This code is a little bit longer but it ensures no errors when the  tag contains other attributes.

Comment: This code assumes `random/path/with/different/number/of/dirs/` is not in fact random and with a different number of dirs for all occurrences.  The path could be `a/b/c/d` for one occurence and `x/y/z` for another.  This code assumes the path is always the first match `a/b/c/d`.

Comment: @lololololol I dont understand. My code doesnt care for the path.